# word 2007 "final without markup" as the default

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2007, how do you make "Final" in the Review tab ?  It is rather annoying to have the "Final showing Markup" as default.

Answer (score 6):

From this [document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831771) :

1. Start Word 2007, and then open the Word 2007 document.
2. Set the Review / Track changes setting to Final.
3. Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Word Options.
4. In the left pane, click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.
5. In the left pane, click Privacy Options, and then click to clear the Make hidden markup visible when opening or saving check box.
6. Click OK two times.
7. Make a change to the document. For example, type a space, and then delete the space. Then, save the document.

Note If you do not perform the last step and make a change to the document, the change that you made to the Make hidden markup visible when opening or saving option may not take effect the next time that you open the document.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. #7 is important..